# Python: Converting tuple w list to csv

Tags: python

currently having trouble outputting a tuple with list to list on csv. If the length of this list > 1, for some reason it is converted to a string.

```
def storePPTrainingData(ppTrainingData,tweetDataFile):
    import csv
    with open(tweetDataFile,'wb') as csvfile:
        linewriter=csv.writer(csvfile,delimiter=',',quotechar="\"")
        for tweet in ppTrainingData:
            try: 
                linewriter.writerow([tweet[0],tweet[1]])
            except Exception,e:
                print e
```

See ppTrainingData:

```
ppTrainingData[:1] = [(['bummer', 'got', 'david', 'third', 'day'], 0)]
```

When outputted to CSV:

```
"['bummer', 'got', 'david', 'third', 'day']",0
```

Any pointers would be great, as would like to input list + label into program. ppTrainingData is a list of 20k processed tuples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your output csv file, 0 is also a string. That's what a csv is; a text file. When reading one, Python or Pandas or any other framework might try to also convert what it sees into types. In your case 0 might get converted but the list will not. I used pandas for convenience:

```
>>> tweet = [(['bummer', 'got', 'david', 'third', 'day'], 0)]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(tweet)
>>> df.to_csv("j.csv")
>>> df = pd.read_csv("j.csv")
>>> df['0'].values[0] # this is just because pandas returns arrays
"['bummer', 'got', 'david', 'third', 'day']" # a string!
>>> lst = eval(df['0'].values[0])
>>> lst, type(lst)
(['bummer', 'got', 'david', 'third', 'day'], <class 'list'>)
```

When reading you can try using `eval` or some other method, but you cannot possibly avoid writing strings. You may be able to avoid the quotation marks but it seems a big hassle.

Alternatively, you might consider unnesting the sequence:

```
>>> tweet[0][0] + [tweet[0][1]] # or something similar
['bummer', 'got', 'david', 'third', 'day', 0]
```

And then writing that to a csv. When read, you can take everything but the last element to a list, and the last to another, with some tuple unpacking magic:

```
>>> lst
['bummer', 'got', 'david', 'third', 'day', 0]
>>> *new, zero = lst
>>> new
['bummer', 'got', 'david', 'third', 'day']
>>> zero
0
>>> res = (new, zero)
>>> res
(['bummer', 'got', 'david', 'third', 'day'], 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer mate, it answers what I was asking, however at my limited coding level I have not familiarised myself with pandas. Your latter method was quite understandable, and I gave that a shot. While it works it inputs the list into csv as a string, and that string would be hard to reconvert back into a list upon input back into the program? I am thinking of converting the list into a sentence, then having two columns per row, one for the sentence and one for the label. Converting a sentence back into a list would prove easier... for me anyway. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to write into the csv file. I would do something like :

```
for tweet in ppTrainingData:
    # tweet is something like (['bummer', 'got', 'david', 'third', 'day'], 0)
    words, number = tweet
    # words is something like ['bummer', 'got', 'david', 'third', 'day']
    linewriter.writerow(words + [number])
    # we have written 6 columns to csv file : "bummer","got","david","third","day",0
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, I apologise for my lack of clarification, I would've liked to output as a list so I could read it back in easily, but it seems like a csv file is a text file, and lists are converted to strings. Inputting back in a list converted to a string would prove difficult so I think I will have to convert the list into a sentence, to store in the csv. Thanks for your suggestion, but I would like to have one column for the list (now string), as different lists have different number of entries, and I would like to keep the number of columns the same throughout different rows.